# How to return total time in seconds given a column with only hour-minute-second format

Tags: python, pandas, date, time, seconds

I have a pandas DataFrame with a column with 00:00:00 (hour, minute, second) format.

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['00:01:00', '00:00:30', '00:01:30', '00:00:10']})

       Time
0  00:01:00
1  00:00:30
2  00:01:30
3  00:00:10
```

I need to create a column with the total seconds in the column. **How can I achieve this?**

```
       Time  Time in secs
0  00:01:00          60.0
1  00:00:30          30.0
2  00:01:30          90.0
3  00:00:10          10.0
```

I tried:

```py
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

But this results in the following, which does not match the expected output.

```
       Time        Time in secs
0  00:01:00 1900-01-01 00:01:00
1  00:00:30 1900-01-01 00:00:30
2  00:01:30 1900-01-01 00:01:30
3  00:00:10 1900-01-01 00:00:10
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format = "%H:%M:%S").dt.time` to get the times

Comment: Cool, nice information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have a date, so easiest to work with `Timedelta`, and your format matches exactly what is required. These have exactly the attribute you want: `total_seconds`

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.Time).dt.total_seconds()
#0    60.0
#1    30.0
#2    90.0
#3    10.0
#Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert the time column to a timedelta and divide it by seconds

```
df['Time in secs'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])/pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='S')
```

result

```
df['Time in secs']
0    60.0
1    30.0
2    90.0
3    10.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```